# ActiveModel destroy after calling new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activemodel

I'm working with a controller that follows the resource_controller principle explained [here](http://jamesgolick.com/2007/10/19/introducing-resource_controller-focus-on-what-makes-your-controller-special.html).

As you can see, I don't have full control on the (new, create etc...) all of them preload data, which means if I want to create a new entity let's say `@user` the following code has already been called `@user = User.new`.

The only way I can include some validation is through callbacks, but once the callback decides to cancel the new method, I always end up with a Hash frozen error.
In other words, I can't say

`@user = User.new
@user.destroy`

The only hack I was able to come up with was

`@user = User.new
@user.save
@user.destroy`

Does anyone know a better way, which doesn't involve saving things to the database?
And btw what is the difference between active record and active model?

Answer (score 1):

How about checking if it's been saved before destroying it?

```
@user.destroy unless (@user.new_record?)
```